# hyperlink choice in Django RadioSelect widget

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am using a `RadioSelect` widget and a `queryset` that fetches some files each user has uploaded and it renders fine. The user is supposed to select a radio button to make a file the "current" one with a POST.

However, I do not see in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) any feature of making the label next to the radio button a hyperlink in order for the selection to be clickable so the user prior to select to be able to see the uploaded file and make sure it is the one he/she wants to select.

Here is my class:

```
class goForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
            def label_from_instance(self, obj):
                return  "%s uploaded at %s, %s" % (obj.menu_name ,obj.when_upload.date(), obj.when_upload.time() ) 
        user_choice = MyModelChoiceField(
            widget=forms.RadioSelect,
            queryset=Document.objects.all().filter(who_upload='u'),
            empty_label=None,
            to_field_name='docfile'
            )
        class Meta:
            model = go
            fields = ['working_menu']
```

So how can I return a hyperlink of the obj.menu_name ?

Comment: I think Django would escape any HTML and you wouldn't get what you want either way by using `label_from_instance`, but try it yourself by adding some HTML to the output, like: `"<a href='#'>%s</a> uploaded at %s, %s"`

Comment: It does not work as you guessed Lorenzo.

Comment: you can render the form field as `{{ form.user_choice }}` and then put the link right next to it. Alternatively you can import and use `mark_safe` function `from django.utils.safestring`.

Comment: Thank you very much `WayBehind`, it is towards the right direction !